# Taking 5 different inputs from the user in PL/SQL block using the same variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare 
x number;
begin
for i in 1 .. 5
loop
x:=&no;
dbms_output.put_line(x);
end loop;
end;
```

here what i wanted to do was to take five times input from user in the pl sql block and print it,but what it does it print only one value that is taken at the  compile time,is there any solution for that?

```
Enter value for no: 1
old   7: x:=&no;
new   7: x:=1;
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: Please don't shout in your title.

Comment: You should take input values from the user via **application**. `PL/SQL` is not an interface to accept values from an user. And, using **substitution variables** in `SQL*Plus` would be an horrible idea as I would never prefer giving `SQL*Plus` as an **UI** to the user.

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL is useful for doing operations whithin the database. I don't know a way to read user input in PL/SQL, and you cannot write a GUI either. SQL*plus (the "shell") can take input from the user, but there you cannot easily write loops.

You cannot write a full application in just PL/SQL and SQL*plus. You need some other host language to do this. This is why we have java jdbc, perl DBI and lots of other bindings to programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `&no` is acting as a substitution variable here, that means you have to substitute a value for it. Once you've done that there is no need to accept any further user input; the substitution has been made.

If you want to accept user input, use the [ACCEPT command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm#BACGJIHF):

```
SQL> accept x number format '9999' prompt 'Enter number: '
Enter number: 2
```

However, this won't work in a PL/SQL block because it's not PL/SQL. So, you're in a right mess and doing this 5 times:

```
SQL> accept x number format '9999' prompt 'Enter number: '
Enter number: 8
SQL> exec dbms_output.put_line(&x);
8

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Unless you have a specific need to format command line reports in SQL*Plus you're using the wrong environment in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't. 
PL/SQL is executed inside the database, and the database has no access to the terminal window.

The only thing you could do is:

```
DECLARE 
        a NUMBER;
        b NUMBER;
        c NUMBER;
        d NUMBER;
        e NUMBER;
BEGIN
        a := &NO;
        b := &NO;
        c := &NO;
        d := &NO;
        e := &NO;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(b);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(d);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(e);
END;
/
```

The disadvantage here is that it will always ask the user for 5 values to input. 
Not more, and not less.